# erro ao dar npm start no prompt de comandos

Tags: javascript, node.js

eu estou começando agora com js , e decidi fazer um bot para servidores do discord, como uso bastante a plataforma. comecei assistindo tutoriais, e eu fiz meu primeiro bot hospedando o no Repl.it, como não gostei muito do site, e a maioria dos exemplos e tutoriais são pelo vs code, decidi tentar faazer um pelo vs code, então comecei seguindo o tutorial e adicionando discord.js no meu projeto, seguindo os passos do tutorial tentei dar npm start na pasta do meu bot, e deu um erro, segue o erro e a print do erro:
(node:17552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An invalid token was provided.
at C:\Users\Youtu\Documents\SounnyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RESTMethods.js:36:54
at new Promise ()
at RESTMethods.login (C:\Users\Youtu\Documents\SounnyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RESTMethods.js:35:12)
at Client.login (C:\Users\Youtu\Documents\SounnyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:280:30)
at Object. (C:\Users\Youtu\Documents\SounnyBot\core.js:15:8)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:17552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:17552) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[image: segue imagem caso não tenha entendido]

e minha pasta de scripts está somente com:
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
"start": "node core"
como eu acabei de começar o projeto não tem praticamente nada nela.

Comment: Tentou rodar um ``npm install`` ?

Comment: sim, mas não foi, já exclui o node_modules e o package-lock.json e dei npm update , install , mas nn vai

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que o **token** de acesso provido está errado e isto poderia ser resolvido provavelmente com um bloco **try/catch**.
Se tiver alguma **promise** no seu código tente trocar o token(que é dado no site da api escolhida).Caso não utilize promises nem **apis**.Coloque um bloco try/catch assim:

```
function yourFunction(yourParams){
   try{
       //Your code
   }catch(error){ 
       console.log(error)
   }
}
```

Comment: olá, boa noite, então como citei acima eu sou iniciante, e estou seguindo passo de tutoriais, então poderia me informar onde eu coloco este codiogo, em que pasta ou certo? obriado pelo comentario!

Comment: Você poderia mandar o github do codigo ou uma foto das pastas que ele tem .Pois assim saberia te guiar melhor .Mas a principio você vai colocar o trecho de código que eu te passei em alguma função onde você acessa algum tipo de Token,um código que algum site te passou provavelmente o Discord